# awk print most common string in second column

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to print the top 10 most common strings within a file, line by line from second column

example of input:

```
example123:Example
Example321:Example
Common:String
Common:String
..
```

expected output

```
example
string
...
```

Comment: Hello, did my answer help at all?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the change in case in a typo. If so, then the following works.

```
awk -F: '{print $2}' input.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | awk '{print $2}'
```

### Explanation

To make sense of it, start with the first command, up to the pipe, and run that by itself. Then add the next pipe on sequentially.

- `awk -F: '{print $2}' input.txt`: using `:` as the delimiter, print the second field.
- `| sort`: sort the files so that you can then run
- `| uniq -c`, which compresses adjacent repeated entries into one, while listing the count `-c` of repeats.
- `| sort -rn`: sort the output by the count, in descending order.
- `| awk '{print $2}'`: remove the count number, and just print the string that matched.

I'd normally use `cut` instead of `awk`, but you question asks for `awk`, so… Alternatively, the first command is more simply `cut -d: -f2 input.txt`.